# (Reactjs) "delay" when fetching data using useEffect and useState

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

The below is my code.

What i am doing is a currency converter app by fetching external API. It is guaranteed process.env.REACT_APP_DATA_SOURCE is always correct.

The problem here is: If I change the currency, either inputCurrency or outputCurrency, I need to click "Submit" button twice instead of once to display a correct answer. Why is it the case?

I can't come up with any better wording so I used "delay" in the heading.

Thank you!

```
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Select, Button, ButtonGroup } from '@chakra-ui/react';

function App() {
  const [exchangeRate, setExchangeRate] = useState(7.8491);

  const [inputCurrency, setInputCurrency] = useState('USD');
  const [inputAmount, setInputAmount] = useState(1);

  const [outputCurrency, setOutputCurrency] = useState('HKD');
  const [outputAmount, setOutputAmount] = useState(7.8491);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async (url) => {
      await fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => setExchangeRate(data.conversion_rates[outputCurrency]));
    };

    try {
      let url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_DATA_SOURCE}${inputCurrency}`;
      fetchData(url);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, [inputCurrency, outputCurrency]);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setInputCurrency(e.target.inputCurrency.value);
    setInputAmount(e.target.inputAmount.value);
    setOutputCurrency(e.target.outputCurrency.value);

    let result = inputAmount * exchangeRate;

    setOutputAmount(result);
  };

  return (
    <div className="main-body">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <h3>Set input amount:</h3>
        <input className="inputAmount" name="inputAmount" type="number" />

        <h3>Set input currency:</h3>
        <Select name="inputCurrency">
          <option value="USD">USD</option>
          <option value="HKD">HKD</option>
          <option value="CNY">CNY</option>
          <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
          <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
        </Select>

        <h3>Set output currency:</h3>
        <Select name="outputCurrency">
          <option value="USD">USD</option>
          <option value="HKD">HKD</option>
          <option value="CNY">CNY</option>
          <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
          <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
        </Select>

        <Button colorScheme="blue" type="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>

      <h3>
        {inputAmount} {inputCurrency} is equal to:
      </h3>
      <h3>
        {outputAmount} {outputCurrency}
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating the output amount at the wrong place. First, you update the `inputCurrency` and `outputCurrency` in handleSubmit. This means the useEffect will be 'triggered' and the new exchange rate will be fetched. But that's not gonna happen immediately. Definitely not before result is calculated.

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setInputCurrency(e.target.inputCurrency.value);
    setInputAmount(e.target.inputAmount.value);
    setOutputCurrency(e.target.outputCurrency.value);

    //This will ALWAYS use the old previous exchange rate.
    let result = inputAmount * exchangeRate;
    setOutputAmount(result);
};
```

What you want is to recalculate `outputAmount` whenever the `exchangeRate` or `inputAmount` changes. You can use another useEffect like:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //Take these out from handleSubmit.
    let result = inputAmount * exchangeRate;
    setOutputAmount(result);
}, [inputAmount, exchangeRate])
```

Comment: love you! I edited my code using your idea and it works! a BIG THANK YOU to you!

Comment: accepted, my friend